# Submit form and pass values with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

**Index.html**

```
function drawChart() {
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "server.php?startdate=" + start_date + "&enddate=" + end_date + "&type=" type,
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
    (...)
```

This vars: **start_date, end_date and type** should be obtained by a form without refreshing the page, so I can send it to server.php and do some stuff
How can I do that without change this jsonData structure etc ? 

Because I need it to build charts.

Thanks one more time :)
ps: Notice me if I wasnt clear :)

Comment: You didn't pass start_date and end_date to the drawChart() function. Are they global variables?

Comment: No, that variables should be obtained by a form. That is my problem :S

Comment: **Index.html** should have a form that receive start_date, end_date, type, and send it to **server.php**, in turn will return some data (charts) to **index.html** again.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you get any error messages? Also, I noticed that you forgot a `+` here: `start_date + "&enddate="`.

Comment: You're missing a + here "&type=" type should be "&type=" + type. Are you getting any errors at all? Have you looked at the request / response in your developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining a form (such as the one below) on your page, some jQuery would allow you to grab the values entered into the text fields and store into javascript variables that you can then use in your drawChart() function.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#never_name_a_button_submit').click(function() {
            var start_date = $('start_date').val();
            var end_date = $('end_date').val();
            var type = $('type').val();
        });
    });
function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "server.php?startdate=" + start_date "&enddate=" + end_date + "&type=" type,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
(...)

</script>

<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date"><br />
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date"><br />
    <input type="text" name="type" id="type"><br />
    <input type="button" id="never_name_a_button_submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ill try it tomorow, but it seems be what am I looking for :) thanks

Comment: ive made an alert(start_date), it says "undifined" when i hit the button

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form has an `id` and each of your form inputs have a `name` you can use the jQuery `serialize()` function which will send the form data to the URL in your ajax request. Something like this:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "server.php",
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
```

Notice the addition of the `data` option in the ajax call, where `#myForm` is the id of your form.

So for example if you had

```
<input type="text" name="start_date" />
```

in your form, the ajax request would actually be sent to `server.php?start_date=2012-11-20`

Comment: It might be that..ill try :)

Comment: So if my form was something like this: `<input type="text" name="start_date" /><input type="text" name="start_end" />` ajax call will be `server.php?start_date=2012-11-20&end_date=2012-12-20` ?

Comment: `<form id = "myform">     
Start date: <br/> <input name="start_date" id="start_date" type="text" /><br />
End date: <br /> <input name="end_date" id="end_date" type="text" /><br />
<input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>?`

Comment: For greatest readability, modify your original question with the above HTML form code. Also, be careful with capitalization: "myform" in your comment above, but "myForm" in Brian's solution.

Comment: @skdnewbie Yes that's how it will work, except if you keep the `submit` button it will actually submit your form the normal way, which is not what you want.